# how add a point in an specific position of a string in a column in python

Tags: python, pandas

Hy! I have a dataframe with two columns latitude and longitude with a wrong format that i want to correct. The structure of de strings in columns is the next

| Lat | Long |
| --- | --- |
| -314193332 | -6419125129999990 |
| -313147283 | -641708031 |

I need to append a point in the third position to have this structure:

| Lat | Long |
| --- | --- |
| -31.4193332 | -64.19125129999990 |
| -31.3147283 | -64.1708031 |

how can i do this?

the value being an integer type too, i can configure that if there is a function to edit integers

Answer (score 4):

You can use arithmetic with a conversion to log10 to get the number of digits:

```
N = 2 # number of digits to keep before decimal part
out = df.div(10**np.floor(np.log10(df.abs())+1).sub(N))
```

Output:

```
         Lat       Long
0 -31.419333 -64.191251
1 -31.314728 -64.170803
```

Intermediate (number of digits):

```
np.floor(np.log10(df.abs())+1)

   Lat  Long
0  9.0  16.0
1  9.0   9.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which uses `regex` to replace the first two digits to the same digits plus `.`:

```
df.astype(str).replace(r'(^-?\d{2})',r'\1.', regex=True).astype(float)
```

Output:

```
         Lat       Long
0 -31.419333 -64.191251
1 -31.314728 -64.170803
```